# Uncompress and unarchive the .tar.gz file using cat, tar and gzip on one command line

Tags: linux, tar, cat, gzip

How can I uncompress and unarchive a .tar.gz file using cat, tar and gzip on one command line? Is this even possible?

Comment: Is this a homework question? Why the requirement for cat? Are you aware that GNU/Linux tar can uncompress and unarchive all by itself?

Answer (score 11):

No need for `cat` or `gzip`:

```
$ tar xvzf archive.tar.gz
```

The option string tells `tar` to extract (`x`) in verbose mode (`v`) the compressed (`z`) archive following the `f` flag.

Using all of `cat`, `tar` *and* `gzip` (which is silly, **don't do this**):

```
$ cat archive.tar.gz | gzip -d -c | tar xvf -
```

or

```
$ gzip -d -c archive.tar.gz | cat | tar xvf -
```

When given `-` as the filename, `tar` will read the archive from standard input.

The last two examples suffer from what's commonly called "Useless use of `cat`", since the only thing `cat` does is to shuffle data to the next part of the pipeline.

A slightly better version, without the `cat`:

```
$ gzip -c -d archive.tar.gz | tar xvf -
```

This may actually be a useful thing to know how to do on a system where `tar` doesn't know how to handle compressed archives.

The archaic option string that I've used for `tar` above, without the dash (`-`) in front of it, comes from a time before the dash was commonly used for specifying command line options.  Other utilities that do not use regular option syntax includes `dd` and `mt`, but whereas most implementations of `tar` today *understands* the newer dash options, `dd` usually doesn't. The `mt` command (which controls magnetic tape operations) has acquired some dash options (especially on Linux), but the only non-optional part of the command line is still the command that you'd like to perform on the drive, such as `rewind` or `eof`.

Comment: `v` isn't necessary for the process to complete; it just makes `tar` verbose.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Yep, I like seeing things happening. Will add more info shortly.

Comment: True, but depending on the amount of files in the tarball, a verbose listing could run longer.

Comment: @sleepyweasel Whether this matters or not is a question of personal taste. Personally, I'd rather look at a long listing of files than save a few seconds of time because 1) I can see things are being extracted where I expect them to be extracted, and ) I'm never in that kind of hurry.